# How to seperate Latitude and Longitude Values From the JSON Output?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, cllocation

I am trying two draw route between two location,For that I Fetch all the points from Google Map API Web Service.(`JSON` Output Format). After parsing `JSON` Data and De cording points i stored all points on `NSMutableArray`.
Each array of index contains this type of values.

```
"<+10.90180969, +76.19167328> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/04/12 10:18:10 AM India Standard Time",
```

Now i want to separate latitude and longitude values.

```
latitude  : +10.90180969
longitude : +76.19167328
```

How to get this values from each index of array?

Comment: what kind of response is that? can you show me the whole string?

Comment: Just do some string manipulation man.

Comment: suppose i have a NSSstring, NSString holding the value "<+10.90180969, +76.19167328> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/04/12 10:18:10 AM India Standard Time",
then how to seperate +10.90180969 and +76.19167328 values

Comment: There is pre define function available?

Comment: I am getting error  CLLocation substringWithRange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f52d0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something in a  very crude form and I guess its a brute solution

```
NSString* str =     @"<+10.90180969, +76.19167328> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps  course -1.00) @ 12/04/12 10:18:10 AM India Standard Time";
NSArray* arr = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];

if ([arr count] > 1) {
   NSString* coordinateStr =  [arr objectAtIndex:1];        
   NSArray* arrCoordinate = [coordinateStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];        
    NSLog(@"%@",arrCoordinate);
}
```

Looking at the string it shows that you are printing the description of a CLLocation object "**someObject**" , You can also access the latitude and longitude such as

```
   CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [someObject coordinate];
    NSLog(@" \nLatitude: %.6f \nLongitude: %.6f",location.latitude,location.longitude);
```

OutPut will be : Latitude: 28.621873 Longitude: 77.388897

but this won't give you the signs i.e "+" , or "-"

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ..., I choose the second method.

Comment: Musthafa , you can always refer to the developer documentation and the sample code available at the developer portal developer.apple.com and that is always helpful :) along with StackOverflow. Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

This is just one way to do this.:

```
NSString* str = @"<+10.90180969, +76.19167328> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 12/04/12 10:18:10 AM India Standard Time";//you already have this string.
str = (NSString*)[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@">"] objectAtIndex:0];
// after above performed step, str equals "<+10.90180969, +76.19167328"
str = [str substringFromIndex:1];
// after above performed step, str equals "+10.90180969, +76.19167328"
NSString* strLat = (NSString*)[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* strLon = (NSString*)[[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1];
// after above performed step, strLat equals "+10.90180969"
// after above performed step, strLon equals " +76.19167328"
strLon = [strLon substringFromIndex:1];//<-- to remove the extra space at index=0
```

Comment: I choose the above answer second one

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in my code - tried to adapt to your case:

Header file:

```
@interface CLLocation (String)

+ (instancetype) clLocationWithString:(NSString *)location;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation CLLocation (String)

+ (instancetype)clLocationWithString:(NSString *)location
{
    static NSRegularExpression *staticRegex;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSError *error = NULL;
        //ex: <41.081445,-81.519005> ...
    staticRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)+"
                                                            options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                              error:&error];
    });

    NSArray *matches = [staticRegex matchesInString:location options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, location.length)];

    if (matches.count >= 2) {
        return [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[location substringWithRange:((NSTextCheckingResult *)[matches objectAtIndex:0]).range] doubleValue]
                                          longitude:[[location substringWithRange:((NSTextCheckingResult *)[matches objectAtIndex:1]).range] doubleValue]];
    } else {
        return [[CLLocation alloc] init];
    }
}
```